Schengen visa cover letter
I was initially planning to travel to Spain for 10 days on a tourist visa with my sister, but we have since shortened the trip to 5 days due to work commitments. Should we mention this change in the cover letter for the visa application, so they dont think why duration is just 5 days only or is it fine?
Additionally, do we need to disclose that we will be meeting friends during our visit?


I was initially planning to travel to Spain for 10 days on a tourist visa with my sister, but we have since shortened the trip to 5 days due to work commitments.

You should give the details based on what is known at the time of the application.
So 5 days is fine.

Additionally, do we need to disclose that we will be meeting friends during our visit?

The application form offers (in Field 21) a multiple choice (check-boxes) options for the standard reasons, so you can simply check the ones that apply to your case.


Field 21: Main purpose(s) of the journey:

Tourism
Visiting family or friends





So u saying we should not add this extra stuff "we shortened trip and all due to so and so reason" ?

@sahil There absolutly no reason to do so, since the change happened before the application was made.

Certain travel premises could look weird for being too short. One does not normally fly from Europe to Hawaii for a single day at the beach, but might do so for one day in an office. But five days are not too short for a family event, I'd say.
